# Allow a block to reference classes/modules not currently in scope, but will be in scope when invoked?

Tags: ruby, scope

Is it possible to do something like this in Ruby (1.9.2-p290)?

```
class SomeClass
  include SomeModuleThatProvidesLotOfConstants

  def build(&block)
    singleton_class.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

obj = SomeClass.new
obj.build do
  some_class_method SomeConstant, :an => :option
  ...
end
```

Where `some_class_method` is a method that is available to `SomeClass` (not to instances of it) and `SomeConstant` is a class/module that is in scope inside of `SomeClass`, but would have to be references as `SomeClass::SomeConstant` from outside.

I can get this working if I always pass fully-qualified class names inside my block, but I'm trying to effectively "re-scope" the block when it is invoked.  Is this possible?  I'm pretty sure RSpec and other such tools that make heavy use of blocks achieve something like this :)

Note that while I'm calling class methods from inside the block, I only want the changes to affect this individual singleton class, rather than propogate to all instances.

EDIT | Ok, here's the non-pseudo version of what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm trying to add some DataMapper properties at runtime, but only to singleton classes... I don't want them to suddenly appear across all instances of the model.

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial
  property :title,      String
  property :created_at, DateTime
  ... etc ...

  def virtualize(&block)
    singleton_class.instance_eval(&block)
    self
  end
end

def suspend_post
  @post = Post.get!(1).virtualize do
    property :delete_comments, Boolean
  end
end
```

I know there are other ways to do virtual attributes (I'm currently using a couple of different approaches, depending on the complexity), but I'm just experimenting with a few ideas to avoid cluttering my model definitions with transient methods that are only used for transporting form data in one specific part of the site and don't mean anything when you're reading the source code of the model by itself.  One or two virtual attributes are ok, but as they start to mount up on commonly used models I start to explore things like this ;)

In the above, the resource would have all of the standard properties defined in the concrete class, plus any that are added in the `#virtualize` method.  It's the reference to `Boolean` without the `DataMapper::Property::` prefix that's throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got what you want with respect to methods. If you define `some_class_method` like this:

```
def Foo.some_class_method(name)
  define_method name do
    puts("this is the method #{name}")
  end
end
```

and do

```
f = Foo.new
f.build { some_class_method "new_method" }
f.singleton_methods # => [:new_method]
```

You've defined behavior on just that one instance.

However I don't think you can get what you're looking for with respect to constants. One option would be to use methods instead of constants for those arguments. Another would be to have the client code mix in whatever module defines the constants.

Do keep in mind this is pretty dense metaprogramming, so the complexity may not be justified.

Comment: Thanks :)  I think my pseudo-code may not have been clear enough, as I'm not actually trying to define new methods, I'm trying to invoke a class-level DSL after-the-fact. Invoking the methods is the easy part :) I was hoping there was some trick with `Proc#binding` or some such. I guess I may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
class SomeClass
  SOME_CONSTANT = 42

  class << self
    def some_class_method
      'foo'
    end
  end

  def build &block
    self.class.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

SomeClass.new.build do
  puts "#{some_class_method} #{SOME_CONSTANT}"
end
#=>foo 42
```

Comment: It's just not very DSL-like, having to put the entire thing into a String :)  I'll just abstract away some of the internal DSL I guess.  I just thought this was actually possible already ;)

Comment: Actually, sorry, misread your code.  That approach isn't working for me, for some reason.  The constant in question is a DataMapper property (which is brought into scope on DataMapper models through the use of `include DataMapper::Resource`... but when the block is used inside some other class I get errors like `Undefined constant SomeOtherClass::Boolean`, like my block is trying to load classes in the scope it was declared in, not the scope it's being invoked in.

Comment: If you use DataMapper, I'll update my question to show what I'm actual attempting.

Comment: Perhaps you should have pasted real sample.. `instance_eval` evaluates the block in the scope of the receiver, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Post updated.  By the way, your example would actually modify the class definition if any state changing methods were invoked in the block, since `self.class` returns the concrete class, not a singleton class that is specific to just the current instance.

Comment: Sorry, missed your previous comment earlier and have been to bed :) Yeah, I always thought `instance_eval` evaluated the block in the scope of the receiver too, but it doesn't seem to be doing that here.  I have tried using `self.class` in place of `singleton_class` to no avail.  Thanks for your suggestions anyway :)